# Best way to handle exceptions with a lot of exceptions to handle

Tags: c#, exception

What's the best way to C# exception handling if I have a lot of exceptions to handle?

Will I put all of them in the try block or put as many try blocks as I can?

For example, when I was connecting to a database as follows,

what is the best way to put the try...catch...finally blocks?

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=school.mdb");
conn.Open();
string sql = "select * from sheet1 where student='stu2'";
OleDbCommand command;
command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", reader[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What kind of exceptions do you want to handle? Can you put an example of your try/catch in the code?

Comment: Ugh, why do people double-space their code? It takes up so much vertical room on the screen.

Comment: I don't see you handling any exceptions, and in fact, I don't see any exceptions that you need to handle. Which exceptions do you feel you need to handle?

Comment: Identify the exceptions you want to handle (that can't be prevented by writing good code), and then catch them in order from most-specific to least-specific.  A lot of exceptions can be handled before they become exceptions by writing good code (for example, checking to see if `File.Exists` before trying to open it).

Comment: @lc.  I want to build robust program so I want to deal with all the possible problems that may encounter.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry, it's my first time to ask questions in stackoverflow. I'll keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I want to handle exceptions such as File.Exists and so forth. I want to deal with all possible exceptions.

Comment: @Tim Thank you. If the frequency of the exception is low, I will put it in try...catch blocks, else I will check it with if...

Comment: Writing robust code is a great goal - but exception handling isn't the way to do it.  Robust code should handle as much as possible in the code; exceptions should be just that - an *exception*.  Something not reasonably expected to happen.  Since there are methods within the framework to check for the existence of a file, the file not existing should not be considered an exception - the program should handle it.

Comment: Take a look at this article on MSDN - [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).  If you need further information or something in the article doesn't make sense, come back and ask a new question and folks will be happy to help.

Comment: @Tim `File.Exists` returning `True` does not guarantee another process hasn't deleted your file before you try and access it. This race condition may still need addressing through exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

One little exception-handling hint: your code is not cleaning up after itself in case an exception is thrown. The following code will clean up, whether or not an exception is thrown:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=school.mdb"))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "select * from sheet1 where student='stu2'";
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", reader[i]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Question - has does a just-posted answer become a community wiki?

Comment: That makes sense.  Related question - what is the value in making an answer a community wiki?

Comment: In this case, it's because I didn't intend to gain any rep from this answer. It's really just a formatted comment.

Comment: @Tim That is not really appropriate use of CW for the record.  In this case it really shouldn't be an answer at all, since it doesn't actually answer the question.